# Upgrading Xiaomi HIMO C20 battery

Tags: batteries

Does any one know what is the charger port is for Himo C20 Ebike battery?

I ordered mine it's on its way now I couldn't find the information online.
Also I was wondering if I can add this battery to my Himo C20.

[Aliexpress - 36V 20Ah E-Bike Battery 18650 Lithium ion Frog Batteries For 36Volt Bafang 500W BBS02 250W BBS01 TSDZ2](https://aliexpress.com/item/4000382065486.html)

They are both 36 volts but Himo C20 battery is 10ah and this one is 20ah is that gonna be a problem?

Also how do I do it? Should I just connect the second battery's discharge cable the main battery's charge port?

Comment: Please clarify - do you intend to daisy-chain these batteries?    Charging a battery by discharging another battery is a sure-fire way to kill both batteries, by severely reducing their service life.    Instead you would be better paralleling both outputs together (NOT SERIAL)

Comment: I don't know what daisy chain is but I saw a video on YouTube that some guy extended an electric scooter range by making another battery and plugging the discharge to the charge port of the default scooter battery. In there he said that both batteries should be same voltage I was wondering about the capacities cuz he didn't mention in his video

Comment: I think you're confusing "charge port" with connecting batteries in serial/parallel.   Do not charge one battery off another battery. (which is the same as "plugging the discharge of one to the charge port of the scooter battery" )    Go read https://battlebornbatteries.com/difference-series-parallel-connection-basics/ to learn the difference.  You want to have your batteries in PARALLEL to increase the capacity without increasing the voltage.  If you series them you'd sum the voltages, possibly frying your controller.

Comment: I'm tempted to migrate this to Electronics because its about a battery, not a bike.  Thoughts ?

Comment: That's what gave me the idea https://youtu.be/jSLmV5K3JSA

Comment: Well that's a perfect example of wrong information.   at ~30 seconds he says (paraphrased) "build a second battery, same voltage, into the charge port of whatever scooter you have"   which is either charging the onboard battery off a battery, or assuming the charger (wall adapter's) output voltage is the same as the battery voltage.   You would do better to build a "throw switch" to toggle between either battery as a source, like a fuel-tank selector in a long-range car or a cessna or the emergency fuel tank in a motorbike or Beetle, etc.   In addition, read those comments.

Comment: That throw switch seems like a good idea

Comment: So my bike arrived today and I'm thinking since the battery is removable I can mount the second battery and when the main one runs out I put it out and connect the second one to the port which the main battery connects to https://imgshare.io/image/kXR6Y. That should work right? Do you know the name of the connector port that I would need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your ebike controller doesn't check if the "correct" (original) battery is installed you shouldn't have an issue replacing the 10ah battery with the20ah battery. If however it does check you could theoretically swap the BMS from the 20ah to the 10ah battery but this will most likely not be needed.

The difference in capacity shouldn't be an issue (when using both batteries) as long as both batteries (or at the least the smaller capacity battery) have a BMS (battery management system) or PCM (protection module) with a low voltage cutoff function (to prevent the cells from overdischarhing).

Comment: My plan is to use both batteries at the same time. So I just basically connect the discharge wire from the 20ah battery (the new battery that I'm ordering) to the charge port of the default 10ah battery?

Comment: yes I am quite sure that should work. Regarding the first thing I said in my original answer: Even if your BMS only accepts batteries specifically made for your controller it should not be a problem as long as you have both batteries installed (since the controller will 'accept' the original battery as a 'matching' battery and the other battery which you will put in parallel will just add more capacity).

Comment: In summary: Yes I believe if you connect the outgoing wires of the 20AH battery to the discharge port of the 10Ah battery (sometimes the charge and discharge ports are 1 port (aka 'common port') and in other cases they are seperate ports) it should work just fine. If you do indeed have a seperate charge port it could perhaps work to connect the new 20Ah battery to the charge port of the 10Ah battery but this depends on the minimum charging voltage at which the BMS of the 20Ah battery will charge.

Comment: If for example the small battery is at 80% and the big battery is at 100% the big battery will most certainly charge the small battery via the charge port. However if for example the small battery is at 20% and the big battery is at 50% the voltage of the big (20Ah) battery might be too low for the BMS of the 10Ah battery to continue charging the small (10Ah) battery. You would have to check with Xiaomi to be 100% sure about this. Perhaps someone knows if most bms's will accept a lower charging voltage and if so to what extent.

Comment: @Maarten-Monicaforpresident connecting two batteries together in the way theOP describes way sounds entirely wrong to me. Charging a LiIon battery is much more involved than sticking a voltage across it's terminals, it requires charging management circuitry. It would make much more sense to connect the two batteries in parallel, but I'd still have questions about how the motor controller would deal with that.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I agree connecting the batteries in parallel (discharge side) would be a more suitable option.

Comment: And I thought I will be as simple as mounting the new battery on the bike and connecting it to the charge port of the main battery :-/

Comment: @E-bikenoob that might still be possible but is a much more complex solution which will be more likely to give troubles in the future and it (to what extent this 'solution' will work) strongly depends on the design of the BMS/PCM of the batteries and how they interact.

Comment: @E-bikenoob Regarding the other option (connection batteries' disconnect side in parallel) you have a few options. Solder extra wires to the wires going to the battery connector (frame side), attach an additional battery connector (for connecting the 20Ah battery to these wires). 
This will enable you to remove both batteries.
You could also solder the 20Ah battery directly to the a fore mentioned wires without a battery connector but this way you will not be able to remove the 20Ah battery from the bike (which is a disadvantage).

Comment: @E-bikenoob You can use any connector to connect the battery as long as it can handle enough voltage/current. (Max current can be calculated by dividing Wattage by battery voltage; in your case: I=W/U --> I = 250/36 --> I=6.95Amp current). To be safe use a connector for the battery which can handle a bit more amps (for example 10 Amp).

Comment: @E-bikenoob Additon regarding battery connector: You should also make sure the connector you use to connect the battery cannot be connected the wrong way (wrong polarity).

Comment: I would not advise doing this!!! In theory it could work but in reality when wired in series it's 72V. It would require balance charging and all 18650 cells go into sleep mode when discharged below 2.5V.

Comment: @Dan K the suggestions I made were all regarding parallel connection of the two batteries. Connecting them in series would indeed not be a good idea (partly because the controller most likely cannot handle this voltage and also you risk overheating your motor)